# Getting thumbnail from YouTube JSON Data Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I would like to display the thumbnail of a youtube video in my custom cell. I have the JSON link but I am not sure how I go about getting the actual image? My code is below!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 

*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell";
    RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id obj in topLevelObjects) {
            if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = obj;
                break;
            }
        }


    }

    // Configure the cell...

   // cell.videoThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbNailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSArray *subArray = [subDict objectForKey:@"items"];
    if ([subArray count]) {
        for (NSDictionary *dictItem in subArray) {
            cell.titleLabel.text = [dictItem objectForKey:@"title"];

            NSNumber *totalSeconds = [dictItem objectForKey:@"duration"];
            int *minutes = totalSeconds.intValue/60;
            int *seconds = totalSeconds.intValue%60;
            NSString *finalDuration =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%im %is", minutes,seconds];
            cell.durationLabel.text = finalDuration;


            NSString *separatorString = @"T";
            NSString *firstUploadString = [dictItem objectForKey:@"uploaded"];
            NSString *uploadString = [firstUploadString componentsSeparatedByString:separatorString].firstObject;
            cell.dateUploadLabel.text = uploadString;

            NSString *viewCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictItem objectForKey:@"viewCount"]];
            cell.viewsLabel.text = viewCount;

            NSString *thumbnailURL = [dictItem objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];

        }
    }



    return cell;
}
```

Everything else is working great but what do I do with the thumbnail URL? Thanks!

My code now looks like this...

```
NSString *viewCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictItem objectForKey:@"viewCount"]];
            cell.viewsLabel.text = viewCount;

            NSDictionary *thumbnailDict = [dictItem objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
            //NSString *thumbnailURl = [thumbnailDict objectForKey:@"sqDefault"];
            //UIImage *thumbNailImage = nil;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                NSString *thumbnailURL = [thumbnailDict objectForKey:@"sqDefault"];
                NSLog(thumbnailURL);
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailURL];
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                UIImage *thumbNailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Here in main thread set image to your cell imageView.
                    // e.g.
                    [cell.videoThumbnail setImage:thumbNailImage];
                });
            });





        };
    }



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting thumbnailURL , Mean you are getting image url but you don't know how show the image write ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get `NSData` from that url. Make sure url is valid and available.

```
@try {

    UIImage *thumbNailImage = nil;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSString *thumbnailURL = [dictItem objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailURL];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *thumbNailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Here in main thread set image to your cell imageView.
            // e.g.
            [cell.imageView setImage:thumbNailImage];
        });
    });

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception :%@",exception.debugDescription);
}
```

Comment: use that in dispatch_async block, else tableView scrolling will be broken

Comment: @DebanjanChakraborty- Thanks for direction. I missed that one.

Comment: Fast scrolling will mess this up pretty badly. You'll be getting the wrong image all over the place. Use `AFNetworking`'s `AFImageView` subclass to make this problem much, much easier.

Comment: And there's no need for a try-catch block in this block of code. None whatsoever.

Comment: @GuyKogus - I never did face an issue like you said. Yes @try catch required here. You can not be sure that each time you will get an image, unless you know the server side response. PS - I never use `AFNetworking`, Apple provided class's are way better than to go for any library.

Comment: 1) None of the methods called in the supplied code throw an exception, therefore you don't need a try-catch block. 2) Third party libraries exist so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel. `AFNetworking` is probably the most commonly used library for iOS applications because it makes most networking commands incredibly easy and safe. I stand by it all the way, so do countless others.

Comment: I NSLogged the image URL to make sure it is working correctly and after fiddling with it a bit it is definitely working correctly. It returns a small JPG file. But without throwing any errors the image is showing up blank. I think it may be due to the Queue's but I will update my question do you have any idea why @GuyKogus

Comment: Have you logged to check that the image itself has been created correctly? I often find that the best bet is to call `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));` to check through code.